# Displaying folders in the HDFS

Tags: c#, hadoop, hdfs

is there a possibilty to display only the directories or folders not files in the HDFS ? because the hadoop fs -ls  display every thing in hdfs inluding  files and directories.Am actually working with  c# using the Microsft Hadoop dll.
How can i display directories not files in The HDFS
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`hadoop fs -ls` displays the file/directory list like Unix `ls` format.

```
$ bin/hadoop fs -ls /
Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   3 root supergroup       1366 2016-11-25 07:41 /README.txt
drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2016-11-25 07:41 /dir1
drwxrwx---   - root supergroup          0 2016-11-25 07:40 /tmp
```

Since directory is specified `d` prefix, you can filter out files such as `grep` or anything.

```
$ bin/hadoop fs -ls / | egrep "^d"
drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2016-11-25 07:41 /dir1
drwxrwx---   - root supergroup          0 2016-11-25 07:40 /tmp
```

Comment: THanks , but is there any possibilty using the c# programming including the .Net framework